# coq: elimination of forall quantifier

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I want to prove the following theorem:

```
Theorem Frobenius (A: Set) (q: Prop) (p: A -> Prop) :
  (q \/ forall x : A, p x) -> (forall x : A, q \/ p x).
```

I already got the following piece of the proof:

```
Proof.
intro.
intro.
destruct H.
left.
assumption.
```

But now I am in a situation I don't know what to do. The following things are at my disposal:

```
A : Set
q : Prop
p : A -> Prop
H : forall x : A, p x
x : A
```

And I would like to prove the following subgoal:

```
q \/ p x
```

How can I eliminate the forall quantifier in the given premise

```
forall x : A, p x
```

that is: How can I plug in my concrete x : A so that I can deduce: p x ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate the universally quantified `x` in `H` with [`specialize`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic61) (`specialize (H x)`).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest?

```
Theorem Frobenius (A: Set) (q: Prop) (p: A -> Prop) :
  (q \/ forall x : A, p x) -> (forall x : A, q \/ p x).
intro H.

elim H.
intros Hl x.
left.
exact Hl.

intros Hr x.
right.
apply Hr.
```