# Coq: eliminating `forall`?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am struggling to prove the following theorem (non-empty domain is assumed):

```
Theorem t (A: Set) (P: A -> Prop): (forall a: A, P a) -> (exists a: A, P a).
Proof.
  intros H.
```

Noramlly, having `forall a: A, P a` I would deduce `P c`, where `c` is a constant. I.e. `forall` quantifier would be eliminated. Once that done I would again deduce `exists a` and my simple proof will be `Qed`ed.

However, I can't find right way to eliminate on `forall` in Coq.

I am new to it and I'd like to know how to eliminate `forall` in Coq or what's the better way to prove the above-mentioned theorem?

P.S. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994491/coq-elimination-of-forall-quantifier) answer but it seems to be unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike other logical formalisms (e.g. Isabelle/HOL), in Coq it is perfectly possible to have an empty domain. If you want to prove your statement, you have to assume explicitly that `A` is not empty. Here is one possibility.

```coq
Definition non_empty (A : Type) : Prop :=
  exists x : A, True.

Theorem t (A : Set) (P : A -> Prop) :
  non_empty A ->
  (forall a : A, P a) ->
  (exists a : A, P a).
Proof.
intros [c _] H. exists c. apply H.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks, is that precisely why `False` is defined as an empty type which can not be constructed in any way?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Yes, it is related to that.